# Errors deploying Dart app to app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dart

Sample helloworld app fails to deploy in cloud version of app server
the same app deploys without errors on the local developer instance of appserver

```
C:\Users\Dave\helloworld>gcloud config set project my-project-name

C:\Users\Dave\helloworld>gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml
Updating module [default] from file [C:\Users\Dave\helloworld\app.yaml]
07:58 PM Host: appengine.google.com
{bucket: vm-containers.my-project-name.appspot.com, path: /containers}
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
   oudsdk\gcloud\gcloud.py", line 153, in 
     main()
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
   oudsdk\gcloud\gcloud.py", line 149, in main
     _cli.Execute()
     File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 381, in Execute
    post_run_hooks=self.__post_run_hooks, kwargs=kwargs)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\calliope\frontend.py", line 274, in _Execute
    pre_run_hooks=pre_run_hooks, post_run_hooks=post_run_hooks)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 887, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\calliope\exceptions.py", line 78, in TryFunc
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\ap
    pengine\app_commands\deploy.py", line 154, in Run
    self.__Run(args, project, deployables)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\ap
    pengine\app_commands\deploy.py", line 207, in __Run
    info.runtime, path, bucket)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\appengine\lib\images\push.py", line 135, in BuildAndPushDockerImage
    r.Push(image)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\appengine\lib\images\registry.py", line 121, in Push
    for line in output_lines:
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\docker\d
    ocker\client.py", line 279, in _stream_helper
    socket_fp = socket_obj(_sock=self._get_raw_response_socket(response))
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\docker\d
    ocker\client.py", line 260, in _get_raw_response_socket
    self._raise_for_status(response)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\docker\d
    ocker\client.py", line 89, in _raise_for_status
    raise errors.APIError(e, response, explanation=explanation)
    docker.docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Invalid
    registry endpoint https:/: Get https://
    49161/v1/_ping: EOF. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with a
    n unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry 
    to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the regis
    try's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /
    etc/docker/certs.d//ca.crt")

After reverting to 1.3.0

```
C:\Users\Dave\helloworld>gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml
Updating module [default] from file [C:\Users\Dave\helloworld\app.yaml]
10:52 AM Host: appengine.google.com
```

{bucket: vm-containers.my-project-name.appspot.com, path: /containers}

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
   oudsdk\gcloud\gcloud.py", line 153, in 
    main()
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\gcloud\gcloud.py", line 149, in main
    _cli.Execute()
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 381, in Execute
    post_run_hooks=self.**post_run_hooks, kwargs=kwargs)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\calliope\frontend.py", line 274, in _Execute
    pre_run_hooks=pre_run_hooks, post_run_hooks=post_run_hooks)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 887, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\calliope\exceptions.py", line 78, in TryFunc
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\ap
    pengine\app_commands\deploy.py", line 154, in Run
    self.__Run(args, project, deployables)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\ap
    pengine\app_commands\deploy.py", line 207, in __Run
    info.runtime, path, bucket)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\appengine\lib\images\push.py", line 134, in BuildAndPushDockerImage
    boto_path=config.BOTO_PATH)) as r:
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\appengine\lib\images\registry.py", line 148, in __enter**
    self.Start()
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\googlecl
    oudsdk\appengine\lib\images\registry.py", line 97, in Start
    self._registry.Start()
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appen
    gine\google\appengine\tools\docker\containers.py", line 480, in Start
    self._image.Build()
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appen
    gine\google\appengine\tools\docker\containers.py", line 309, in Build
    raise ImageError('Image with tag %s was not found' % self.tag)
    google.appengine.tools.docker.containers.ImageError: Image with tag google/docke
    r-registry was not found

Comment: Is there really a space in `docke r` in `google/docke r-registry` (last line of your error output)?

Comment: user3329151 have you a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with the ISO image that is shipped with Docker 1.3.1 and I had the same issue.

You should do the following:

- Ensure that Boot2Docker ISO Image for 1.3.0 is used. This is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://www.dartlang.org/cloud/setup.html#setup-instructions).

I ran into the same problem and this is what I ended up doing - though you might be better off following the correct steps as in the documentation:

- I downloaded the ISO Image from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.3.0/boot2docker.iso
- Modified the Virtual Box VM setting for boot2docker-vm to use this ISO
- Reinitialized everything
- Note this means you have to get the docker images again for google.

Alternately, if you still want to be with 1.3.1 , then you can look at this thread on how to provide this setting.[Remote access to a private docker-registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710153/remote-access-to-a-private-docker-registry)

Comment: Thanks Romin, I was at 1.3.1 and I went back to 1.3.0.  The results are different, any comments?