# Docker private registry

Tags: ubuntu, docker

On a virtual server ubuntu 14.04 I have installed docker and I try to push to a local registry an image.
I followed [this guide on the Docker blog](http://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/) but when I try to push the image I have this output:

> Error: Invalid registry endpoint https://xx.xx.xx.xx/v1/: Get https://xx.xx.xx.xx/v1/_ping: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry xx.xx.xx.xx` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/xx.xx.xx.xx/ca.crt

I try to add `--insecure-registry xx.xx.xx.xx` in `/etc/default/docker` file and restart docker service.
Docker fails to start with message `/proc/self/fd/9: 17: /etc/default/docker: --insecure-registry: not found`.

PS: I run my registry in a docker container

Comment: stupid question: did you replace xx.xx.xx.xx with your registry's hostname/ip address?

Comment: use `--insecure-registry=xx.xx.xx.xx` (don't forget the '=')

Comment: for st0ne: is fqdn of my private registry repo.my.lan
@mbarthelemy doesn't work, also with '='

if i start docker daemon with  docker -d --insecure-registry repo.coro.ced.it it works!

Comment: I was typing --insecure-registry xx.xx.xx on a nel line instead of using DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry xx.xx.xx.xx"

Comment: You could also add you CA certificate to the trusted certs

Comment: @joh.scheuer i'm using an unsecure private repo for testing purpose   over plain http

Comment: Oh sorry didn't read well enough, sorry :)

Comment: Did any of these fix your problem?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 12.04 and Docker 1.4.1. Here is my solution:

```
$ sudo docker push "[host:ip:v6:addr:ess:is:here]:5000/myImage"
FATA[0002] Error: Invalid registry endpoint https://[host:ip:v6:addr:ess:is:here]:5000/v1/: Get https://[host:ip:v6:addr:ess:is:here]:5000/v1/_ping: EOF. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry [host:ip:v6:addr:ess:is:here]:5000` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/[host:ip:v6:addr:ess:is:here]:5000/ca.crt
```

So, I have an error.

```
$ ps axwww | grep /usr/bin/docker
14655 ?        Ssl    2:06 /usr/bin/docker -d
14869 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep /usr/bin/docker
```

Notice, that there is no extra arguments to /usr/bin/docker.

```
$ echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry [host:ip:v6:addr:ess:is:here]:5000"' | sudo tee -a /etc/default/docker
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry [host:ip:v6:addr:ess:is:here]:5000"
$ sudo service docker restart
docker stop/waiting
docker start/running, process 15615
```

Let's check if arguments appeared:

```
$ ps axwww | grep /usr/bin/docker
15615 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/docker -d --insecure-registry [host:ip:v6:addr:ess:is:here]:5000
15663 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep /usr/bin/docker
```

Yes, they do. One more attempt:

```
$ sudo docker push "[host:ip:v6:addr:ess:is:here]:5000/myImage"
The push refers to a repository [[host:ip:v6:addr:ess:is:here]:5000/myImage] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Pushing repository [host:ip:v6:addr:ess:is:here]:5000/myImage (1 tags)
511136ea3c5a: Image successfully pushed 
27d47432a69b: Pushing [================================================>  ] 189.8 MB/197.2 MB 0
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to verify that the DOCKER_OPTS actually took hold using the ps command.

Answer (score 2):

simply running this `docker run -p 5000:5000 -d registry` will get you in to trouble with https.

I found this tutorial helpful : [How To Set Up a Private Docker Registry on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04)

It basically sets up a reverse proxy with nginx to access the private registry. I have 1 vagrant box with the registry and a different vagrant box pulling stuff from this registry. It works :)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the docker registry directly on a host is quite frustrating.
The easiest way to setup a local docker repository is to use the docker-registry docker image.
Simply execute

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -d registry
```

and docker should download the official docker registry image.
After that you can attach to container and customize the setup.
Source:
http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/12/using-private-docker-repository-registry.html

Answer (score 0):

In the host

```
  1- install docker machin
      curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.14.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine && \
      sudo install /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
  2- Remove any proxy entry in /etc/systemd/system/docker.....
  3- Edit the daemon.json file, whose default location is /etc/docker/daemon.json
      {
      "insecure-registries" : ["myregistrydomain.com:5000"]
      }
  4- Generate crt: 
      $mkdir -p certs
      $openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout certs/domain.key -x509 -days 365 -out certs/domain.crt
      Be sure to use the same name myregistrydomain.com as a CN.
      Copy the domain.crt file to /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistrydomain.com:5000/ca.crt on every Docker host. You do not need to restart Docker.

  5- pull registry image from docker hub 
      docker run -p 5000:5000 --name myregistry registry
```

In the client

```
  1- Remove any proxy entry in /etc/systemd/system/docker.....
  2- Edit the daemon.json file, whose default location is /etc/docker/daemon.json
      {
      "insecure-registries" : ["myregistrydomain.com:5000"]
      }
```

Comment: I'm not too sure that you have to add "insecure-registries" on the host AND the client.