# docker unrecognised service when i run this command sudo service docker stop

Tags: docker

i am trying to push a image to myown docker registry.I got invalid endpoint registry error.When i googled it i got solution of running these commands.This is the link [Remote access to a private docker-registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710153/remote-access-to-a-private-docker-registry.But) when i try to run first command i.e service docker stop i will get always service is not recognised.Rest other docker commands run fine.I googled it but not getting much help.If any one can help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What os are you running on the host? What version of Docker? How did you install Docker?

Comment: i am running docker on host ubuntu 14.04.docker version 1.0.1.I installed docker by runing this ommand  apt-get -y install docker.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because you installed docker.io so the service is called docker.io?
Does `service docker.io stop` work?

See https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/ for how to get a much newer version.