# error in docker build publish plugin

Tags: build, docker, jenkins-plugins, docker-registry

Can you please help me for configuring the [jenkins docker build publish plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+publish+Plugin).
I have setup artifactory for docker repo and trying to push  image build from github docker file.

Following is the error I am getting :

```
Error response from daemon: Invalid registry endpoint https://     
https://artifactory.corp.inmobi.com/v1/: 
Get https:// https://artifactory.corp.inmobi.com/v1/_ping: dial tcp: unknown port tcp/. \
If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, \
please add `--insecure-registry  https:` to the daemon's arguments. \
In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, \
no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/ https:/ca.crt

Build step 'Docker build and publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: does it work if u use `docker` command directly to push to artifactory ? better to use certificated CA for your domain as well to avoid https problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is not related with Jenkins Docker build and publish plugin, see source code [DockerBuilder.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-build-publish-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/dockerpublish/DockerBuilder.java), it will execute the `docker` command directly.

If you artifactory server (https://artifactory.corp.inmobi.com) is not official CA certificated, please check [Remote access to a private docker-registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710153/remote-access-to-a-private-docker-registry) to enable it in your jenkins server (which has docker daemon)

Or ask your IT admin to apply official CA certification for https://artifactory.corp.inmobi.com