# artifactory as docker registry

Tags: docker, artifactory

I tried to set up artifactory as docker registry as shown in this video: http://www.jfrog.com/video/artifactory-docker-integration/

However, I don't have SSL installed in artifactory so I'm using the --insecure-registry flag. (as shown in [error in docker build publish plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700816/error-in-docker-build-publish-plugin) and [Remote access to a private docker-registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710153/remote-access-to-a-private-docker-registry))

Anyway, I don't know how to figure out the artifactory as docker registry url so I can do this:
curl -k -uusername:password "http://sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com:8081/artifactory/api/docker/docker-images"

This page, http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories, shows at the bottom that something called a reverse proxy might be needed? Is this true and if so how do I install such a thing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason behind requiring a reverse proxy in front of Artifactory is related to a Docker client limitation - you cannot use a context path when providing the registry path, e.g sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com:8081/**artifactory/api/docker/docker-images** is not valid.
The Docker client assumes you are working with one big registry for all images, while Artifactory allows you to manage multiple registries (repositories) on the same server.

To overcome this issue you should setup a reverse proxy which will allow the Docker client to send requests to the root context and forward those requests to the correct repository path in Artifactory. For example, forwarding requests from `sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com:8888/` to `sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com:8081/artifactory/api/docker/docker-images`

The Artifactory documentation contains configuration examples for [NginX](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories#DockerRepositories-NginxConfiguration), [Apache](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories#DockerRepositories-ApacheConfiguration) and [HAProxy](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories#DockerRepositories-HAProxyconfiguration).
Notice that there are different configurations for Docker registry API v1 and v2.

After setting up the reverse proxy, the Docker client should use the proxy in order to access Artifactory.

If you are using the --insecure-registry flag there is no need to configure an SSL certificate. With older versions of Docker, before this flag was [introduced](https://docs.docker.com/v1.3/release-notes/#version-132) (Docker 1.3.2) it was a mandatory requirement.

Comment: I see. But why does nginx need an SSL certificate? If I pushed to a real docker registry (as opposed to artifactory) would it still need a cert?

Comment: If you are using the --insecure-registry flag then there is no need to setup an SSL cert

Comment: I used nginx and used the url for docker registry that they have in the example at http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories#DockerRepositories-WorkingwiththeDockerV1RegistryAPI which is https://artprod.company.com. I start nginx and ping that url but I get unknown host" `ping https://artprod.company.com`. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: You should use the domain name of your server instead - sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com