# How to push docker images through reverse proxy to artifactory

Tags: nginx, docker, continuous-integration, artifactory

I've an issue pushing my docker image to artifactory [Artifactory Pro Power Pack 3.5.2.1 (rev. 30160)] (which is used as a docker registry).

I have docker version:

```
$ sudo docker version
Client version: 1.5.0  
Client API version: 1.17  
Go version (client): go1.3.3  
Git commit (client): a8a31ef/1.5.0  
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64  
Server version: 1.5.0  
Server API version: 1.17  
Go version (server): go1.3.3  
Git commit (server): a8a31ef/1.5.0
```

I've followed this link http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories and this one [artifactory as docker registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662029/artifactory-as-docker-registry)
I create a docker registry in artifactory called `docker-local` and enable docker support for it.
My artifactory doesn't have an option where I can say docker v1 or v2 like in [this document](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories) so I'm assuming it uses docker v1.

Artifactory generated these for me:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>sdpvvrwm812</id>
        <name>sdpvvrwm812-releases</name>
        <url>http://sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com:8081/artifactory/docker-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>sdpvvrwm812</id>
        <name>sdpvvrwm812-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com:8081/artifactory/docker-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Though something's not working with these settings.

I installed the reverse proxy `nginx` and copied these settings into its `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

> http {
>
> ```
> ##
> # Basic Settings
> ##
> [...]
>
> server {
>     listen 443;
>     server_name sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com;
>
>     ssl on;
>     ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com.crt;
>     ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com.key;
>
>     access_log /var/log/nginx/sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com.access.log;
>     error_log /var/log/nginx/sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com.error.log;
>
>     proxy_set_header Host $host;
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
>     proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
>     proxy_read_timeout 900;
>
>     client_max_body_size 0; # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads
>
>     # required to avoid HTTP 411: see Issue #1486 (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1486)
>     chunked_transfer_encoding on;
>
>     location /v1 {
>         proxy_pass http://sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com:8081/artifactory/api/docker/docker-local/v1;
>     }
> } }
> ```

I generated my ssl key as shown at http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html and placed in the 2 directories

```
/etc/ssl/certs/sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com.crt;
/etc/ssl/private/sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com.key;
```

I'm not sure how to ping the new docker registry, but doing

```
 sudo docker login -u adrianus -p AT65UTJpXEFBHaXrzrdUdCS -e adrian@company.com http://sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com
```

gives this error:

> FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with
>   error: Get https://sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com/v1/_ping: dial tcp
>   172.25.10.44:443: connection refused. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add
>   `--insecure-registry sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com` to the daemon's
>   arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's
>   CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate
>   at /etc/docker/certs.d/sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com/ca.crt

BUT the certificate `/etc/docker/certs.d/sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com/ca.crt` exists so what's going on?

```
sudo curl -k -uadrianus:AP2pKojAeMSpXEFBHaXrzrdUdCS "https://sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com"
```

gives this error:

```
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

I do start docker client with:

```
sudo docker -d --insecure-registry https://sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com
```

Could it be that since my docker registry is `http://sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com:8081/artifactory/docker-local` and docker and nginx are looking for `http://sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com:8081/artifactory/docker-local`**/v1**?

**Any clues how to get docker to push images to artifactory?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<distributionManagement/>` part is for maven. It's a bit facepalm that Artifactory 3 shows maven snippet for Docker repos (fixed in Artifactory 4, you're welcome to upgrade), so please disregard it.

Generally with Docker you can't use /artifactory/repoName. It's Docker limitation, your registry must be **hostname:port**, without any additional path.

That's exactly why you have to configure the reverse proxy. What you are doing in your nginx config is forwarding all the requests to `sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com:443/v1` to `http://sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com:8081/artifactory/api/docker/docker-local/v1`, which is correct thing to do.

Please note that the location for certificates should be `/etc/docker/certs.d/sdpvvrwm812.ib.tor.company.com/`, not `/etc/ssl/certs/`.

Comment: I found other blogs giving different locations where to place the certs. So far none have worked including your method. I am trying buying the certs as opposed to me generating them and will try that. Will accept this answer if those certs work.