# Remote communication with private docker registry issues

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I have set up the registry server as below:

```
docker run -d --name p_registry -e SETTINGS_FLAVOUR=local -e STORAGE_PATH=/reg_storage -v /data/private-registry/storage:/reg_storage -p 5000:5000 registry
```

So, now I can push to this registry locally using

```
docker push localhost:5000/hello:tag1
```

But when I tried to push it from another machine, to this registry, it bails out:

```
docker push 1.2.3.4:5000/hello:tag1

Error: Invalid registry endpoint https://1.2.3.4:5000/v1/: Get https://1.2.3.4:5000/v1/_ping: EOF. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry 1.2.3.4:5000` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/1.2.3.4:5000/ca.crt
```

Now, after that I tried various other options:

```
Edit /etc/sysconfig/docker
other_args=--insecure-registry=1.2.3.4:5000
```

And then restarted docker using "service docker restart". This didn't work either. Every time, I tried to push, it gave me the invalid registry endpoint.

I even tried doing as below:

```
vi /etc/default/docker
DOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS --insecure-registry=1.2.3.4:5000"
```

even the one above gives the endpoint error.

Can somebody help here ?

Ref: [Remote access to a private docker-registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710153/remote-access-to-a-private-docker-registry)

Answer (score 1):

`DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 1.2.3.4:5000"` should work

Comment: I think your answer could be true. The issue that I later realized were with the network itself, I was not able to telnet to 5000 on 1.2.3.4 from the machine which was pushing the image. I am going to try something tomorrow and will provide an update.

Comment: Here is the reason, why it was not working before. I was adding DOCKER_OPTS on the Docker registry server and not the deamon/client. It works fine if I update the /etc/sysconfig/docker file with other_args=--insecure-registry=1.2.3.4:5000.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo docker -d --insecure-registry 1.2.3.4:5000
```

This worked for me . Please try it and let us know.

Comment: Error 1: 
I think my issue is more related to the iptables rules. Have you made any changes there ??
Error 2:
Also, I am getting an EOF error:
FATA[0002] Error: Invalid registry endpoint https://1.2.1.2:5000/v1/: Get https://1.2.1.2:5000/v1/_ping: EOF
Error 3:
After getting error 2, I added the ip to the /etc/hosts on the docker host. If I try "docker push docker:5000/test" it tries to use https and if I try "docker push docker/test", it is asking me for a username and password. Is this expected ??

Comment: I have found out that the initial command specified...... docker run -d --name p_registry -e SETTINGS_FLAVOUR=local -e STORAGE_PATH=/reg_storage -v /data/private-registry/storage:/reg_storage -p 5000:5000 registry .......... had only -p 5000:5000(this serves as localhost) Please run using -p 1.2.3.4:5000:5000 Before doing this please restart docker with the commands which i have specified above. Also while pushing use docker push 1.2.3.4:5000/test.When you are try to use "docker push docker/test" it is asking username and password as it is trying to push image "docker/test"in the public domain

Comment: Here is the reason, why it was not working before. I was adding DOCKER_OPTS on the Docker registry server and not the deamon/client. It works fine if I update the /etc/sysconfig/docker file with other_args=--insecure-registry=1.2.3.4:5000 and restart the docker service or when I run `sudo docker -d --insecure-registry 1.2.3.4:5000` on the docker client/daemon.